# Json FIle ObjectId and NumberInt

Tags: json, mongodb

I have tried to Debug this JSON code any help will be much appreciated
I have used Json Lint. The problem is around it "_id" and NumberInt
I dont Want to parse the NumberInt as String.
What am i Missing?

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("596e0b80a12dda2f1b939770"),
    "driver_name": "test",
    "driver_id": NumberInt(1),
    "loc": [22.281547, 70.7762118],
    "driver_status": NumberInt(1),
    "isdevice": NumberInt(1),
    "car_type": NumberInt(69),
    "booking_status_flag": NumberInt(0),
    "booking_status": null,
    "createdAt": "14/7/2017  14:2:12",
    "updatedAt": "14/7/2017  14:2:12",
    "feature_flag": NumberInt(0)
}
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Nopes didn't get the question